# Setting fragments by tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, message-passing, fragmenttransaction

How do I go about setting my `Fragments` by tag since I did not explicitly make them in my `XML` so I can't use `findbyID`.

I have 4 `Fragments` in an Activity and want to pass data back and forth from the `Fragments` but I keep getting error

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.project.myproject.app.Fragment.addToList()' on a null object
>   reference

I don't think I am setting my `Fragment's` tags right so could someone please link me to an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

Set the tag for fragment:

```
YourFragment fragment = getFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, fragment, "YOUR_TAG").addToBackStack("YOUR_TAG").commit();
```

Get the fragment:

```
private YourFragment getFragment() {
    YourFragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YOUR_TAG");
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new YourFragment();
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Gotcha, I was switching fragments from fragments. Thanks!